# Cassandra updates not working consistently

Tags: java, cassandra, astyanax

I run the following code on my local (mac) machine and on a remote unix server.:

```
public void deleteValue(final String id, final String value) {
    log.info("Removing value " + value);
    final Collection<String> valuesBeforeRemoval = getValues(id);
    final MutationBatch m = keyspace.prepareMutationBatch();
    m.withRow(VALUES_CF, id).deleteColumn(value);
    try {
      m.execute();
    } catch (final ConnectionException e) {
      log.error("Unable to delete  location " + value, e);
    }
    final Collection<String> valuesAfterRemoval = getValues(id);
    if (valuesAfterRemoval.size()!=(valuesBeforeRemoval.size()-1)) {
      log.error("value " + value + " was supposed to be removed from list "  + valuesBeforeRemoval + " but it wasn't: " + valuesAfterRemoval);
    }
...
  }

protected Collection<String> getValues(final String id) {
  try {
    final OperationResult<ColumnList<String>> operationResult = keyspace
            .prepareQuery(VALUES_CF).getKey(id).execute();
    final ColumnList<String> result = operationResult.getResult();
    if (result.isEmpty()) {
      log.info("No  value found for id: " + id);
      return new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    return result.getColumnNames();
  } catch (final ConnectionException e) {
    log.error("Unable to retrieve session " + id, e);
  }
  return new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Locally, that line is never executed, which makes sense:

```
log.error("value " + value + " was supposed to be removed from list "  + valuesBeforeRemoval + " but it wasn't: " + valuesAfterRemoval);
```

but that line is executed on my dev server:

[ERROR] [main] [n.o.w.s.d.SessionDaoCassandraImpl] [2013-03-08 13:12:24,801]
[] - value 3 was supposed to be removed from list [3, 2, 1, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8] but it wasn't: [3, 2, 1, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8]

- I am using com.netflix.astyanax
- Both my local machine and the remote dev server connect to the very
  same cassandra instance.
- Both my local machine and the remote dev server run the very same test
  creating a new row family, and adding 10 records before one is deleted.
- When the error occurs on dev, log.error("Unable to delete 
  location " + value, e); was not executed (i.e. running the deletion
  command didn't produce any exception).
- I am 100% positive that no other code is affecting the content of the
  database while I am running the test on dev so this isn't some
  strange concurrency issue.

What could possibly explain that the deleteColumn(value) request runs without producing any error but still does not remove the column from the database?

ADDITIONAL INFO

Here is how I created the keyspace:

```
create keyspace sessiondata
    with placement_strategy = 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy'
    and strategy_options = {replication_factor:1};
```

Here is how I created the column family values, referenced as VALUES_CF in the code above:

```
create column family values
    with comparator = UTF8Type
;
```

Here is how the keyspace referenced in the java code above is defined:

```
final AstyanaxContext.Builder contextBuilder = getBuilder();
final AstyanaxContext<Keyspace> keyspaceContext = contextBuilder
        .forKeyspace(keyspaceName).buildKeyspace(
                ThriftFamilyFactory.getInstance());
keyspaceContext.start();
keyspace = keyspaceContext.getEntity();
```

where getBuilder is:

```
  private Builder getBuilder() {
    final AstyanaxConfigurationImpl conf = new AstyanaxConfigurationImpl()
    .setDiscoveryType(NodeDiscoveryType.NONE)
    .setRetryPolicy(new RunOnce());

    final ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl poolConf = new ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl("MyPool")
    .setPort(port)
    .setMaxConnsPerHost(1)
    .setSeeds(value);

    return new AstyanaxContext.Builder()
    .forCluster(cluster)
    .withAstyanaxConfiguration(conf)
    .withConnectionPoolConfiguration(poolConf)
    .withConnectionPoolMonitor(new CountingConnectionPoolMonitor());
  }
```

SECOND UPDATE

- First, the issues are not solely related to deletes.  I observe similar problems when updating records in the database, reading them, and not being able to read the updates I just wrote
- Second, I created a test that does 100 times the following operations:

  - write a row into cassandra
  - update that row in cassandra
  - read back that row from cassandra and check whether the row was indeed updated, and checking again regularly after delays if it wasn't

  What I observe from that test is that:

  - again, when I run that code locally, all 100 iterations pass right away (no retry ever needed)
  - when I run that code on the remote server, some of the iterations pass, some fail.  When they fail, no matter how large the delay (I wait up to 10 seconds), the test always fail.

At this point, I am really not sure how any cassandra setup could explain this behavior since I connect to the very same server for my tests and since the delays I insert are much larger than any additional latency I may need to run the test when connecting from my local machine.

The only relevant difference seems to be which machine the code is running on.

THIRD UPDATE

If in the test mentioned in the previous update, I insert a delay between the 2 writes, the code starts passing if the delay is >= 1,000 ms.  A delay of, say, 100 ms doesn't help.  I also modified the builder to set the default read and write consistencies to the most demanding: ALL, and that had no impact on the results of the test (still failing about half of the time unless delay between writes >1s):

```
final AstyanaxConfigurationImpl conf = new AstyanaxConfigurationImpl()
.setDiscoveryType(NodeDiscoveryType.NONE)
.setRetryPolicy(new RunOnce()).setDefaultReadConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.CL_ALL).setDefaultWriteConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.CL_ALL);
```

Comment: Are you aware of the tombstone behavior and are you guarding against it? I am not familiar with the astyanax API but when you perform a deletion, the item in question will keep appearing in results until Cassandra cleans it up, and you need to look carefully at the result to see if the item is actually deleted or not.

Comment: Well, no, I didn't know anything about tombstone behavior and from what I read about it, it could conceivably be the cause though that wouldn't explain well why it happens on my machine and not one dev, unless perhaps the delay for me to connect to cassandra is long enough that entries have time to disappear when they don't if I run on dev.  In any case, I will look at this more closely under that angle that you just suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Column deletes won't show up in responses back from Cassandra, only row deletes will.  So this is a case of you not reading back what you immediately wrote.  Cassandra has this behaviour when using eventual consistency.  What replication strategy and replication options are you using?  What consistency levels do you read and write at?  Most likely the delete hasn't propagated and your read uses a different node that hasn't seen the delete.  Maybe your connection from your unix box is faster than your mac so you only see it there.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you both describe the same issue and were correct indeed: I inserted 1-second delays before reading the data I had deleted and didn't see any inconsistency.  Does at least one of you want to put your comment as an answer so that I accept it? Richard, I am using placement_strategy = 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy' and strategy_options = {replication_factor:1}; And I can see now that I can set the consistency level for my queries to override whatever default Astyaniax uses.

Comment: If you really are using replication_factor 1 this can't explain it unless you are using ConsistencyLevel ANY for writes, which almost certainly isn't the default for Astyanax.  With RF 1 data is always consistent, apart from CL.ANY writes.  Can you paste your schema?

Comment: @Richard I added the info you requested along with how I created my keyspace in the bottom section ADDITIONAL INFO in my post. Also an important clarification is that despite adding 1-second delays between writes and reads, I _still_ get errors when running my code on dev while I have never any error when running my code locally, even though, again, in both cases I connect to the same cassandra servers.  That tombsone behavior couldn't account for that behavior, could it?

Comment: @Richard I provided an UPDATE at the bottom of the description.  I am still at loss on that one...

Comment: Hi, from what I can read this looks a lot like the problems I had before understanding Consistency levels. It seems the default Read/Write consistency level is ONE, this is consistent only if you have ONE cassandra node. Have you tried changing to QUORUM? This setting would make data consistent for any number of nodes in the cluster.
Do you have more than one node in you cluster? Or is a one cassandra instance case?

Comment: @le_douard In my last update (update #3), I show the consistency level set to ALL, which to my understanding should add even more constraint than QUORUM, no?  I will try QUORUM just to make sure and comment on the ticket if the result changes.

Comment: You are righ. ALL guarantees that any mutation or query to cassandra will wait to have heard back from all clusters before returning. QUORUM will return if a "quorum" (let's say 2 out of 3, for a 3 instances cluster). Could you give me more details on the set of you

Comment: Could you give me more details on the set of your cluster? Is it only one instance? If it is not then try to make you replication factor to be 3 (if you have at least three nodes).
If you have only one cassandra instance then technically CL_ONE is both QUORUM and ALL.
A trick might be to play with the read_repair_chance setting of the keyspace.http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/configuration/storage_configuration#read-repair-chance

Answer (score 1):

To debug, try printing the full row instead of just the column names. When I say the full row I mean the column name, column value and the time stamp. A long shot is clocks are wrong on one of your test machines and this is throwing out your tests on the other.

Another thing to double check is that ip is indeed what you think it is, in both your application and cassandra. When you retrieve it print it between something, like println("-" + ip "-"). Before and after your try block for the execute in deleteSecureLocation do a get for only that column, not the entire row. I'm not too sure how to do that in astynax, on the cli it would be get[id][ip].

Something to keep in mind is that a delete won't fail even if there's nothing to delete. To cassandra it's a write, the only thing that will make it a delete is if on read it's the latest timestamped entry against that row/column name.