# Cassandra updates are not always consistent

Tags: java, cassandra, astyanax

I'm using **Astyanax 1.56.42** with the latest version of **Datastax Community (Apache Cassandra 1.2.6)** on a fresh two-node-Cassandra-cluster with a two-node Glassfish-cluster and I discovered some issues while writing some new user session entries.

My keyspace setup is:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE test WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 2 };
```

I'm doing UPDATEs to my user sessions table using:

```
KEYSPACE.prepareQuery(CF_USER_SESSIONS)
                .setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.CL_ALL)
                .withCql("INSERT into usersessions (uid, (...)) VALUES (?, (...));")
                .asPreparedStatement()
                .withUUIDValue(uid)
                (...)
                .execute();
```

and after that try to read exactly this session with:

```
result = KEYSPACE.prepareQuery(CF_USER_SESSIONS)
                .withCql("SELECT * from usersessions where uid=?;")
                .asPreparedStatement()
                .withUUIDValue(uid)
                .execute();
```

**this read sometimes fails (= no rows returned)**. "Sometimes" means that it doesn't fail at all if my cluster is nearly idle. But it does more often if it is under heavy load despite the setConsistencyLevel-Attribute is set to "ALL" on the UPDATE-statement.

The interesting thing is: **A delay "solves" this issue**. If I try to do a manual SELECT on the cqlsh later on the new session shows up - but too late for my second query.

What am I doing wrong? Is this a bug? How can I be sure that ConsistencyLevel.CL_ALL works as desired?

(My question is somehow related to [Cassandra updates not working consistently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15342621/cassandra-updates-not-working-consistently), but I'm doing something different.)

EDIT: My Keyspace is set up by using:

```
CONTEXT = new AstyanaxContext.Builder()
    .forCluster("test cluster")
    .forKeyspace("test")
    .withAstyanaxConfiguration(new AstyanaxConfigurationImpl()      
        .setDiscoveryType(NodeDiscoveryType.RING_DESCRIBE)
        .setCqlVersion("3.0.0")
        .setTargetCassandraVersion("1.2")
    )
    .withConnectionPoolConfiguration(new ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl(CONNECTION_POOL_NAME)
        .setPort(9160)
        .setMaxConnsPerHost(100)
        .setSeeds(SOME_CLUSTER_SEEDS_IP_AND_PORT)
    )
    .withConnectionPoolMonitor(new CountingConnectionPoolMonitor())
    .buildKeyspace(ThriftFamilyFactory.getInstance());

CONTEXT.start();
KEYSPACE = CONTEXT.getClient();
```

EDIT #2:
I've set consistency level to "ALL" on all my queries and I've switched the replication_factor to 1. Furthermore I have switched to one single (application server) client to ensure this has nothing to do with the client-timestamps. Reads and writes are done synchonously, but the problem still occurs randomly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting up a consistency level on the read as well, to be sure you are doing things correctly, e.g

```
result = KEYSPACE.prepareQuery(CF_USER_SESSIONS)
                .setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.CL_ALL)
                .withCql("SELECT * from usersessions where uid=?;")
                .asPreparedStatement()
                .withUUIDValue(uid)
                .execute();
```

Let me know if that helps and then we can go from there.

Edit: also, if that doesn't work, try setting up replication factor to 1 and if that doesn't work, try reading/writing to a single node.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out in the next days.

Comment: I've set consistency level to "ALL" on all my queries and I've switched the replication_factor to 1. Furterhmore I have switched to one single (application server) client to ensure this has nothing to do with the client-timestamps. Reads and writes are done synchonously, but the problem still occurs randomly. Do you have other ideas?

Comment: Sorry @Chris, I have no idea what can be wrong, unless something is wrong with the clock implementation you are using for your inserts. Try debugging to see if it is the case and you have two or more inserts with the same timestamp. A cassandra's peculiarity which I have discovered is if you have two inserts with the same timestamp and key, the insert that has a higher byte value of col name, will take precedence, so it might be something to look at.

Comment: @Nikola - Thanks! I had the same problem and it was caused by clock drift.